# Alternative for print_r in php for iphone(objective-c)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've started with objective-c/iphone programming a couple of days ago, and still having some problems converting from other languages.. I'm currently testing around with NSArrays, and NSMutableArrays, and it's really annoying that I haven't found any method for effectively displaying the contents of my arrays (without creating loops and displaying row by row).

Is there some easy method like print_r in PHP or console.log in javascript(w/Firefox && firebug) ?

Really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `NSLog`, e.g.:

```
NSLog(@"This is my NSArray: %@", [myNSArray description]);
```

Comment: NSLog() already calls `-description` on the object. What really needs to be done is NSLog(myArray) or NSLog(@"mArray: %@", myArray);

Comment: NSLog(myArray) will bring up a warning in SDK 3.2. I'd advise going with a formatted string. I would also advise explicitly specifying the description method.

Comment: It is true, I always use a formatted string anyway :D. However I fail to see the point of explicitely calling description?

Comment: Issuing the description explicitly makes it absolutely clear, when reading the code, what NSLog will be showing, when dealing with types that do not offer `-description`. You don't have to use it, if you don't want to. I prefer to and would recommend this to others.

Comment: However, it's explicitly clear if you just read the documentation... http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: Whatever. Use NSLog(myArray) if you want to, as well. *shrug*